# try/catch(OperationCanceledException) vs ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Microsoft [recommends](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/) to handled cancelled task by using `try/catch` with `OperationCanceledException`. At the same time, it is possible to wrap an executed task with continuation using `.ContinueWith()` which will swallow `OperationCanceledException` and not throw. It looks as continuation is still handling exception internally, but doesn't bubble it up.

Given a cancellable task (takes in a cancellation token) on a hot execution path, would it be still advised to use `try/catch(OperationCanceledException)` or continuation approach?

For example:

```
await Task.Delay(delayValue, cts.Token);
```

Could be handled via

```
try
{
  await Task.Delay(delayValue, cts.Token);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException) 
{
  // token triggered cancellation
  return;
}
```

or via

```
var task = await Task.Delay(delayValue, cts.Token).ContinueWith(t => t);
if (task.IsCancelled)
{
  // token triggered cancellation
  return;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use await instead? Show a [mcve] to help better understand the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi the question is not about wherever `await` can or cannot be used. It's about how to handle the task that is cancelled via cancellation token. Minimal description was provided, but I'll add code snippets to make it crystal clear. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - It's not a [mcve] until it can be copy, pasted, and run.

Comment: @Darem the second snippet compiles and works just fine. What's returned is a task, not a void.

Comment: @SeanFeldman sory I was looking wrong!

Comment: In the case you presented it is just a matter of preference. They both achieve the same result and are pretty readable and verbose about their behaviour. It gets more complicated when you replace `Task.Delay` with your custom method though and for that reason I would go with `try/catch` all the time.

Comment: @FCin correct, they both achieve _exactly_ the same. That's out of question. The real question is would `try/catch` approach be still advised on a hot path with multiple invocations per second or would continuation be a better option.

Comment: I doubt that either would be the actual bottleneck in your code. And if it is, why not *[measure it](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sticking strictly to the question rather than the motivations, I ran a benchmark with BenchmarkDotNet:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class CancelBench
{
    private int delayValue = 15;

    private CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken(true);

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task<bool> Exception()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(delayValue, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // token triggered cancellation
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task<bool> ContinueWith()
    {
        var task = await Task.Delay(delayValue, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => t);
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            // token triggered cancellation
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

According to the results, the `ContinueWith` method is 5x faster:

```
                    Method |        Mean |      Error |    StdDev |  Gen 0 |  Gen 1 |  Gen 2 | Allocated |
-------------------------- |------------:|-----------:|----------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|----------:|
                 Exception | 13,823.6 ns | 105.359 ns | 93.398 ns | 0.0916 |      - |      - |     496 B |
              ContinueWith |  2,843.0 ns |  14.300 ns | 13.376 ns | 0.0496 | 0.0076 | 0.0038 |     276 B |
```

That said, you can go even faster by avoiding the jump to the threadpool for the continuation:

```
    [Benchmark]
    public async Task<bool> ContinueWithSynchronously()
    {
        var task = await Task.Delay(delayValue, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => t, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            // token triggered cancellation
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
 ContinueWithSynchronously |    505.2 ns |   2.581 ns |  2.414 ns | 0.0277 |      - |      - |     148 B |
```

Now we're 27x faster.

Of course, it begs the question whether saving 10µs is actually going to make a difference in your application. If it is, then you probably want to avoid `async` altogether.

```
    [Benchmark]
    public Task<bool> NoAsync()
    {
        return Task.Delay(delayValue, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => t.IsCanceled, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }
```

```
                   NoAsync |    397.7 ns |  5.290 ns |  4.948 ns | 0.0281 |      - |      - |     148 B |
```

---

Edit: I'll need to spend some time on that last benchmark because I'm **really** surprised that it allocates as much memory as the async version. I wonder if the compiler is already doing that optimization behind the scenes (there was some talk about adding that feature on .net core, but I'd be surprised it has already been ported to .net framework), or there could be something going on with BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` is a very nice optimization, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes `await` will split your code into a initiating task and a continuation task. Many awaits will result in many tasks. This is the big advantage of using async/await - you don't have to deal with this complexity. It is better not to mix them. Anyway, await is simple, you can't add too many options. `ContinueWith` on the other hand has several options. Among them is the overload permitting you to add [TaskContinuationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2). Without knowing what your final purpose is, this lets you use both continuation and the exception:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

try
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cts.Token)
        .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Continued"), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);
    Console.WriteLine("Hihi...");
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```